How to get file diff of two s3 buckets, when you need profile to access the buckets?
I found a few answers to my question, here is the closest: shell - How to get the file diff between two S3 buckets? - Stack Overflow
The above link suggests using:
aws s3 sync s3://bucket s3://bucket2 --dryrun

However, my issue is that to access one of my bucket, I need to run:
aws s3 ls --profile xxxxx s3://xxx.aws-xxxxxx.rawdata.us-east-1/raw/nxxx/xxx/2024/04/02/

i.e. I have the extra --profile.
Trying to access the bucket without the --profile results in an error being thrown:An error occurred (AccessDenied)
Just to clarify - my intention is to get diffs of the file content if possible, rather than just the filename.

What type of data you're trying to compare?

Why can't you use --profile xxxx with the sync command?  Further, if you want to compare contents, you'll probably need some level of custom code to either compare the ETags and/or download and compare contents.

If this is a significant amount of data, you might consider launching a temporary EC2 instance, downloading both sets of data to it, and do your diff there.

Amazon S3 does not offer a diff capability. To obtain a diff of the contents, you will need to download both sets of data to your own computer and run the command locally.
Also, it would appear that you are accessing each bucket via a different set of credentials, so it would not be possible to run one S3 operation against both buckets simultaneously unless you add a Bucket Policy to one bucket that permits access via the credentials associated with the other bucket.

Thanks you for the answer. I thought so, but I hoped there may be some capability so I thought I'd ask at least.
